# Windows 10 on Special Devices

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10

We are preparing for next year when Windows 7 goes EOL and obviously we're looking at Windows 10. My group supports systems that are connected to instrumentation to conduct research. These systems could run for weeks at a time and cannot be interrupted.

I have to tell you that Windows 10 scares the bejesus out of me because of the number of patches Microsoft releases and because of the significant changes the patches are making. I personally have not had greatest experiences from the Windows 10 patch cycles.

I was curious how other people handle patching machines of this type? I have made a case with our network team to segment the systems from the standard network but have not had much success. It also doesn't matter because our security team still requires us to apply security patches to the systems even though they are segmented.

While doing some research I found Windows 10 S which seemed very promising. It seems like a stripped down version of Windows 10 without all the fluff that we don't need on these type of systems. Unfortunately the main requirement is that all applications need to be installed from the Microsoft store. We have tons of special and very expensive applications so this is not going to work for us.

Once again, I am curious to hear how other businesses support devices of this type. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For system that need less update I would go for Windows 10 LTSB.

The **L**ong **t**erm **s**ervice **b**ranch (LTSB) mean it will never look for **upgrade** (for new build), but only security **update**

> The Long-term Servicing Channel is available only in the Windows 10
>   Enterprise LTSB edition. This build of Windows doesn’t contain many
>   in-box applications, such as Microsoft Edge, Microsoft Store, Cortana
>   (limited search capabilities remain available), Microsoft Mail,
>   Calendar, OneNote, Weather, News, Sports, Money, Photos, Camera,
>   Music, and Clock. Therefore, it’s important to remember that Microsoft
>   has positioned the **LTSC model primarily for specialized devices**.

and some more information;

> Enterprise LTSB is a long-term support version of Windows 10
>   Enterprise released every 2 to 3 years. They are supported with
>   security updates for 10 years after their release, and intentionally
>   receive no feature updates. Some features, including the Windows Store
>   and bundled apps, are not included in this edition.[6][1][3] The 2019
>   release of this edition is expected to be called Windows 10 Enterprise
>   LTSC.[7]

or from another blog;

> LTSB is only for rare mission-critical devices. “It’s more important
>   that these devices be kept as stable and secure as possible than up to
>   date with user interface changes,” explains the documentation.

So I think it's the path to go for you.

On another side I do not think Windows 10 S is for you into your case, as Windows 10 S restrict the app that run on it, to only the universal app, so it can be a problem in your case, and it don't stop all the upgrade, which can cause downtime.

> Does it run all Windows programs?
>
> No. The most important part of the Windows 10 S configuration is a
>   setting that prevents it from running any apps that aren't included
>   with Windows 10 or available through the Windows Store.

Comment: Thank you! I made a mistake. I found LTSB the other day but for some reason when I searched again I thought it was Windows 10 S. LTSB is what I want to do some testing on to see if it will fit our needs. Thanks for clearing that up.